# What is the use case for imageantialias($img, false)

Tags: php, use-case, php-gd

I don't understand why in `PHP` when using the `imageantialias` function you need to pass in a Bool to say if you want to enable anti-aliasing or not.

It feels counter intuitive to call a function with a parameter to say don't do anything.

Is there a use case for calling it with false that I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps to disable anti-aliasing on an image that is already enabled for anti-aliasing ... ie process the same image twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing false doesn't tell the function to do nothing, but to turn antialiasing off, if it was on. A usecase would be drawing to an image with antialiasing, later wanting to draw some more without antialiasing.

Comment: Ah, excellent - I didn't know you could turn anti-aliasing off on an image that had already had it.  That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is an enable/disable function.

So if I call:

```
imageantialias($image, TRUE);
```

...then anti-aliasing is enabled for `$image`. And if I then call:

```
imageantialias($image, FALSE);
```

I have disabled it again.